# Is there an order in which a mother cat takes Kittens when she is relocating?

Tags: cats

I noticed that my cat always has a particular order of taking her kittens. I don't know why this is. Does it have something to do with Weight, fur color or birth order. Is it just random??
Is there an Evolutionary reason for this.

Comment: Is the smallest one always last?

Comment: They all look the same to me... There's three kittens.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no particular rule cats follow. There's no evolutionary purpose to using a particular criterion.

However, there is a benefit to sticking to the usual order, and that's a simple memorization technique. This isn't unique to cats.

If I asked you to list the 26 letters of the alphabet, you will instinctively list them alphabetically, which is the order you're most familiar with.
If I asked you to specifically list them in a random order, it'd be incredibly hard for you to (a) not fall into a pattern and (b) make sure you didn't forget a letter.

For the same reason, it makes sense for a mother cat to want to ensure (b) that she doesn't forget any of her kittens. So it makes sense for her to use an internal checklist. Since she cannot move her entire offspring at the same time, this logically means she has to do it one by one, thus enforcing some sort of sequence.

So the likely answer here is that we can't know why the mother's checklist is ordered the way it is, but we can assume that it's done for the express purpose of *not forgetting someone*.

Comment: I am not sure this is a reasonable argument, if there is still at least one kitten in the  old place she knows she needs to come back.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: The presence of a kitten is noticeable. The **absence** of a kitten less so.